# Is there a way top open a modal from selecting a node from vis.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm trying to open a modal when clicking on a node within a network map i have made using vis.js

I am unsure about where I would place the data-target tag,but I'm not sure if that's the issue, below is the JS that I have written to handle a click action as well as the modal

Currently the data-target is declared within the div tag where the network map is placed after it has been generated (I know this is wrong)

The JS is being Generated in PHP hence the PHP var being thrown in there

Click Action -

```
network.on( 'click', function(properties) {
     var ids = properties.nodes;
     var clickedNodes = ".$nodes.".get(ids);
     console.log('clicked nodes:', clickedNodes);
     console.log('/monitoring/loadNode/'+clickedNodes[0].id);
     $( '#myModalDeviceDetails' ).html('<h1><center><font color=\'white\'>Loading</font></center></h1>');
     $( '#myModalDeviceDetails' ).load( '/monitoring/loadNode/'+clickedNodes[0].id ).show();
 });
```

Modal-

```
<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="myModalDeviceDetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Device Details">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Device Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                loading...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that is a bootstrap modal. It has functions like the following:

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

I would recommend hiding the modal when you load the page and than just show it.

Comment: how can I pass a parameter (linke node id) to the modal view?